# Make second word stick to the right

Tags: html, list, css, html-lists

As you can see in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/cmfL2643/40/), I have a list, where every child is of this form:

> A: B

How can I make B stick to right? I tried `float: right;`, but that didn't help. There is some improvement if I adjust `padding-right: 1em;`, but the value should differ from device to device.

CSS:

```
ul li {
    display: table-row;
}
ul li span {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 12px;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right: 1em;
}
ul li span:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: -12px;
}
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the classes for the `ul li` and `ul li span` as follows :

```
ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}
ul li span {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 12px;
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 1em;
    float: left;
}
```

See this below :

```css
.center_ol {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-position:inside;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}
ul li span {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 12px;
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 1em;
    float: left;
}
ul li span:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: -12px;
    /* compensate for padding-left: 12px; */
    border-bottom: dashed 2px #54687a;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><span>Name:</span>Charis Spiropoulos</li>
    <li><span>Birth:</span>10/02/1996</li>
    <li><span>Foot:</span>R</li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT : The code can be further simplified to :**

```
ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: right;
}
ul li span {
    padding-left: 12px;
    float: left;
}
```

See this below :

```css
.center_ol {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-position:inside;
}
ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: right;
}
ul li span {
    padding-left: 12px;
    float: left;
}
ul li span:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: -12px;
    /* compensate for padding-left: 12px; */
    border-bottom: dashed 2px #54687a;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><span>Name:</span>Charis Spiropoulos</li>
    <li><span>Birth:</span>10/02/1996</li>
    <li><span>Foot:</span>R</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Perfect. Because you improved your answer, I am going to upvote another answer of yours I like, as a thank you gesture.